# Where to put code for formating DB content in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel (and in frameworks general) and not sure about the right "place" for a formatting function.

A short desciption of my problem:
Different tables refer to an enumeration table. The enumeration table keeps a link to an icon, a color, a name and a describtion. I need to format this information in different ways. e.g. 
"simple"
 name
"detailed"
 name, description etc...

Now I'm not sure what's best place to put the code:

- create a custom helper seems to be a too generic place for such issue
- putting in in the model would be the easiest way but seems to me violaton of MVC.
- the view violates the "don't repeat yourself" because I need it in different views
- the template itself? maybe..
- or create a dedicated blade like phpincludes.enumerationfomat ?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: In my projects I format data in models. As a result, I have all the necessary functions.
getLastName, getFirstName, getFullName.
This approach is good if you do not need to do complicated data operations.

Comment: Interesting. Are you just doing "plain" formatting things, like First Name, Last Name or are you also doing a full HTML code as well? e.g. img tag + some text

Comment: Only formatting data. I think it's a bad practice to use <html> in the backend. If you need blocks with layout then I think that there should already be a ready solution for Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to solve:

The answer is: ["component"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots)